python3.12.3 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
I have removed the virtualenvs/<Project> folder and run pipenv install but still hit this error.
$ pipenv install
Loading .env environment variables...
WARNING:pipenv.vendor.dotenv.main:Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 4
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /usr/src/MyProject/PythonRestAPI/Pipfile
Using /usr/bin/python (3.12.3) to create virtualenv...
⠙ Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.12.3.final.0-64 in 147ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/khteh/.local/share/virtualenvs/PythonRestAPI-6TwrpjXm, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/khteh/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==24.0
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator

✔ Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: /home/khteh/.local/share/virtualenvs/PythonRestAPI-6TwrpjXm
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed!
⠋ Locking...False
INFO:pip.subprocessor:Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/puiterwijk/flask-oidc.git /tmp/pip-temp-tui5zq7r/flask-oidc_b66a7df8d9a3410f9aca9d12bc33c344
WARNING:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.vcs.git:Did not find branch or tag 'refs/pull/144/head', assuming revision or ref.
INFO:pip.subprocessor:Running command git fetch -q https://github.com/puiterwijk/flask-oidc.git refs/pull/144/head
INFO:pip.subprocessor:Running command git checkout -q f9e4367098f269160edca4c4601b98372aae8c65
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 675, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 661, in main
    _main(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 645, in _main
    resolve_packages(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 612, in resolve_packages
    results, resolver = resolve(
                        ^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 592, in resolve
    return resolve_deps(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 918, in resolve_deps
    results, hashes, internal_resolver = actually_resolve_deps(
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 691, in actually_resolve_deps
    resolver.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 446, in resolve
    results = resolver.resolve(constraints, check_supported_wheels=False)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 76, in resolve
    collected = self.factory.collect_root_requirements(root_reqs)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 534, in collect_root_requirements
    reqs = list(
           ^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 490, in _make_requirements_from_install_req
    cand = self._make_base_candidate_from_link(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 228, in _make_base_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 297, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 226, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 308, in _prepare_distribution
    return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 525, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 640, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    dist = _get_prepared_distribution(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 71, in _get_prepared_distribution
    abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 54, in prepare_distribution_metadata
    self._install_build_reqs(finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 124, in _install_build_reqs
    build_reqs = self._get_build_requires_wheel()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 101, in _get_build_requires_wheel
    return backend.get_requires_for_build_wheel()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 751, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return super().get_requires_for_build_wheel(config_settings=cs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_impl.py", line 166, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return self._call_hook('get_requires_for_build_wheel', {
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_impl.py", line 321, in _call_hook
    raise BackendUnavailable(data.get('traceback', ''))
pipenv.patched.pip._vendor.pyproject_hooks._impl.BackendUnavailable: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
    obj = import_module(mod_path)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1310, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-157ro1de/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import distutils.core
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/khteh/.local/bin/pipenv", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
             ^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/cli/options.py", line 58, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs, windows_expand_args=False)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 92, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 209, in install
    do_install(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 164, in do_install
    do_init(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 672, in do_init
    do_lock(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/routines/lock.py", line 65, in do_lock
    venv_resolve_deps(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 859, in venv_resolve_deps
    c = resolve(cmd, st, project=project)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 728, in resolve
    raise RuntimeError("Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!")


distutils was removed in Python 3.12. Is this maybe related to no module named distutils....but distutils installed? and Why did I get an error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'??
Have you tried installing it manually?
python -m pip install setuptools


I am aware of this and have read through most of the SO posts but none helps!

Please consider updating your question with things you already tried, that is very important information for everybody who wants to help you.
